# How to get php to run in same file with html code in eclipse?

Tags: php, html, eclipse

I am trying to display an index.php in a web browser. These are the contents of index.php:

```
<?php

echo "PHP Part";
?>

<html>
<h1> html part </h1>
</html>
```

This only prints out html part to the screen of the browser. Why isn't the php being displayed?

the page source looks like:

```
<?php
echo "PHP Part";
?>
<html>
  <h1>html part</h1>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have the PHP interpreter installed? Something like LAMP or WAMP? Or at least Apache + PHP properly configured?

Comment: What does the source look like (in the browser)?

Comment: No, I will download that now and get back to you in a second

Comment: I added what the source looks like.

Comment: Well, you have to first understand the concepts behind all this: you can't just open a PHP file in your computer and expect PHP code to be interpreted. If you do that, you will get this result: PHP code will be ignored, because the browser doesn't understand it. You must call the file through a webserver (Apache, for example), which must be attached to the PHP interpreter, which will properly interpret and execute your PHP code. LAMP or WAMP will simplify all that for you, installing the whole environment.

Comment: I installed wamp and turned the server online and it still isnt printing the php part.

Comment: What URL do you have in your browser? Is it something like http://localhost..., or something like file:///.... ?

Comment: It is http://127.0.0.1:8020/example/assets/www/index.php . That's where my index.php is

Comment: Well, this is correct. Something must be wrong with Apache and PHP communication. I never used WAMP, but I guess there is somewhere in it's settings which binds file extensions to the PHP interpreter. Normally, .php is always bound to it, but I can't think about anything else that may be wrong. Other than that, you can check Apache and PHP log files for clues.

Comment: Ok, by the way, the php works if I place my php file within the www file of the WAMP folder. (The example/assets/www is a whole different location).

Comment: Then you may have an .htaccess file there (or in a parent folder) disabling PHP interpreter there. By the way, .htaccess files are used to override and change default Apache behavior for specific folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Install Wamp or Xampp Server in your PC 
If You Installed WAMP than save this file in WWW folder (it lies in wamp folder)

If You Installed Xampp than save this file in htdocs folder (it lies in xampp folder)

after that make sure your xampp or wamp server is running

go to your browser

write
localhost/filename.ext

**MAKE SURE YOU SAVED YOUR FILE AS .PHP**

Comment: That worked, does that mean we have to work in this directory?

Comment: @user2463517 yes you have to keep your files in that specific directory so that can be executed using server & you can add more folders in there if you want to but than url will be like localhost/foldername/document.ext & please accept my answer if you think it solved your issue(Correct mark right after my answer)